# Can I link an Action to an Operation?

Tags: class, relation, enterprise-architect, operation

I have object of type **Class** and in this class I have one **Operation** named **setCookie()**.

Is it possible create object of type **Action** (or Activity) which is related to Operation setCookie()?

Idea is to create activity diagram with Action/Activity items derived from Class Operations. Because I want to propagate Name and Note information previously described on Class.

Answer (score 2):

Your wording is a bit weird, but basically yes. You drag an operation of your class in an AD and EA will create a call behavior.

[image]

Once you rename the operation EA will also change the classifier displayed in braces:
[image]

Comment: Thanks Geert this is very handy. Exist any shortcut to go from this Action call to source operation Notes. I need to read/edit this Operation Notes directly. The best way will be to see source operation Note window in properties of course. Im also looking for linking between Class and Instance where I want to read/edit class attributes/operation from Instance.

Comment: In Properties (floating)/Properties/Call/Behavior the signature is shown as FQN. You can navigate via the ellipsis. In order to find it in the browser you need either a query or a script.